# Change default directory of createproject.sh (html5boilerplate)

Tags: html, build, boilerplate

I use the html5boilerplate. I would like to change the directory in which createproject.sh script creates a a copy of my html5boilerplate repo. How would I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It currently creates the folder under your Git repository, why do you need to create it elsewhere?  And why can't you simply move it after creation?

Comment: I want to create it in my default project folder which different from my git repo folder of the html5boilerplate. Of course I can move it but I would like to avoid it for convenience. Thanks for asking.